# Spring Boot application with Jaeger

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, jaeger, opentracing

I am using below GitHub link to setup opentracing with [Jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger)
for microservices hosted in kubernetes env and it works fine for Java apps like Jenkins.
https://github.com/lucas-matt/auto-tracing-webhook

https://medium.com/opentracing/opentracing-on-kubernetes-get-yer-tracing-for-free-7a69cca03c8a

However when I try to setup tracing for any Spring Boot application, it does not show any tracing in Jaeger UI.

After some research, I found that I need to add some starter code to trace Spring Boot application as given in below GitHub. However I am confused now, where to add this starter code.

https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger

I am using below agent to trace and seems like I need to add some flag for Spring Boot here but I am not getting exactly.

```
JAVA_AGENT = ' -javaagent:/mnt/auto-trace/opentracing-specialagent-1.7.0.jar -Dsa.tracer=jaeger -Dsa.log.level=FINE'
```

Please suggest!

Comment: According to those docs, you just add it to your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` and it should work.

Comment: do you want me to modify the pom.xml / build.gradle of application which i am trying to trace ?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Jaeger and springboot few years ago. In a dockerized environment, I remember you have to supply few environment variables to the application, something like:

```
JAEGER_AGENT_HOST=jaeger-agent.example.io
JAEGER_AGENT_PORT=5775
JAEGER_SAMPLER_TYPE=const
JAEGER_SAMPLER_PARAM=1
JAEGER_SAMPLER_MANAGER_HOST_PORT=jaeger-agent.example.io:5778
JAEGER_REPORTER_LOG_SPANS=true
```

Then, you need to define the bean:

```
@Bean
public io.opentracing.Tracer jaegerTracer() {
  return new com.uber.jaeger.Configuration("myApp")
    .withSampler(SamplerConfiguration.fromEnv())
    .withReporter(ReporterConfiguration.fromEnv())
    .getTracer();
}
```

Comment: I have these defined already but it does not give springboot capability.

Comment: I found my old project, I forgot to mention a piece of configuration. I've updated the answer above